# Validate password field on entry and when empty

Tags: javascript, html

How do I validate a password field on entry and when empty (including *spaces* entered)?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() 

{
$("#login_btn").click(function(){
    if($("#pass").val() == "") {
        $("#error").show("slow");
    }
    else if($("#pass").val() != "") {
        $("#error").hide("slow");
    }
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="login">
    <div id="login_header"><h2>Sign in</h2></div>
    <div id="dept">Department
        <select>
            <option value="CO" selected>CO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="pass">Password
        <input type="password">
    </div>
    <div id="error">
        Required field cannot be blank
    </div>
    <div id="btn">
        <input type="button" value="Sign in" id="login_btn">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfTHc/1/

Comment: By "on entry" you mean every time a character is inserted?

Comment: Yeah but not including blank spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#pass").val()` doesn't make sence because `#pass` is a `div`, not password field. Fixed version:

```
$("#login_btn").click(function () {
    var pass = $.trim($("#pass input").val());
    if (!pass) {
        $("#error").show("slow");
    } else {
        $("#error").hide("slow");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfTHc/3/

Comment: How about if there is a blank space like - "      ", that should be viewed as blank

Answer (score 0):

Use the keypress event and in the validation function trim the value retrieved from the widget before validating it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login_btn").keypress(function(){
        var pass = $("#pass input").val();
        if($.trim(pass) == "") {
            $("#error").show("slow");
        }
        else  {
            $("#error").hide("slow");
        }
    });

});
```

**Edit**: amended the selector as correctly noted by dfsq's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.trim and just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login_btn").click(function(){
        if($.trim($("#pass input").val()).length == 0) {
            $("#error").show("slow");
        } else {
            $("#error").hide("slow");
        }
    });

});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Soldier/C9es6/